# Hyperledger Fabric CA Certificate Error with Fabric Samples deployment

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I was trying the steps mentioned for the deployment of Asset Transfer Basic Chaincode mentioned here.
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/asset-transfer-basic

I could deploy the TypeScript and Go variants of the chaincode successfully. However the Application is not starting up due to the following error related to CA certificate. Request your help to identify this issue.

:~/Code/fabric/fabric-samples/asset-transfer-basic/application-gateway-typescript$ npm start

asset-transfer-basic@1.0.0 start
node dist/app.js

channelName: mychannel
chaincodeName: basic
mspId: Org1MSP
cryptoPath: /home/gokulalex/Code/fabric/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com
keyDirectoryPath: /home/gokulalex/Code/fabric/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/User1@org1.example.com/msp/keystore
certPath: /home/gokulalex/Code/fabric/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/User1@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
tlsCertPath: /home/gokulalex/Code/fabric/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
peerEndpoint: localhost:7051
peerHostAlias: peer0.org1.example.com

******** FAILED to run the application: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/gokulalex/Code/fabric/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/User1@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/cert.pem'] {
errno: -2,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: '/home/gokulalex/Code/fabric/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/User1@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/cert.pem'
}

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is related to how the network was created (using the `test-network/network.sh` sample script).

If created *with* the `-ca` option, as described in the asset-transfer-basic sample [README](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/asset-transfer-basic#readme), the client certificate for User1 is created in the filename that the sample application is trying to load.

If the network was created *without* the `-ca` option, the cryptogen tool (rather than the CA) is used to create crypro credentials, and the certificate for User1 is written to a different filename in the same directory.